# How to use personal_sendTransaction on RSK?

Tags: rpc, rsk

I'm running an RSK node and I'm trying to send a transaction using `personal_sendTransaction` but I get this error:

```
The local wallet feature is disabled
```

How can I fix this?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to use `personal` module
and this feature implies importing your account to the node.
In the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66420517/194982),
the account is imported into the node by adding
the public key and private key in plain text within
RSKj config file, and this is insecure,
as obtaining access to the file system is enough
to compromise your private key.
Thus this approach should probably be only used for convenience,
and on Testnet or Regtest only -
not for any accounts on Mainnet.

An alternative approach is with the `personal` module enabled,
to use the `personal_importRawKey` RPC to add new accounts.
This way is a bit more secure because the passphrase
is not persisted to the file system.

Even if the machine running the node is compromised,
and the attacker can read the config file,
your private keys would therefore not be compromised as a result.

The full steps are detailed below:

(1) Enable the`personal` module (enabled by default):

```json
rpc {
    modules = [
        ...,
        {
            name: "personal",
            version: "1.0",
            enabled: "true"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

(2) Call the `personal_importRawKey` RPC
to add new accounts:

```sh
curl \
  -X POST \
  --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_importRawKey","params":["YOUR_RAW_KEY", "YOUR_PASSPHRASE"],"id":1}' \
  --header "Content-Type:application/json" \
  http://localhost:4444/
```

(3) Prior to signing transactions using this account,
you will need to call the `personal_unlockAccount`
for the account that you just created.
Note that `DURATION` is optional,
and defaults to `300` (5 minutes).

```sh
curl \
  -X POST \
  --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_unlockAccount","params":["YOUR_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS", "YOUR_PASSPHRASE", DURATION],"id":1}' \
  --header "Content-Type:application/json" \
  http://localhost:4444/
```

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to use `personal` module
and this feature implies importing your account to the node

NOTE: For security reasons, this approach is **not recommended**,
however, it is possible to do.

In order to do this,
you need to configure your node for this in the RSKj config file.
This should be `main.conf` for RSK Mainnet:

(1) Enable the`personal` module (enabled by default):

```json
rpc {
    modules = [
        ...,
        {
            name: "personal",
            version: "1.0",
            enabled: "true"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

(2) Enable `wallet` and add your account:

```json
wallet {
    enabled = true
    accounts = [
        {
            "publicKey" : "<PUBLIC_KEY>"
            "privateKey" : "<PRIVATE_KEY>"
        }
    ]
}
```

After this, you will be able to use
all of the following RPC methods:

- `personal_sendTransaction`
- `personal_importRawKey`
- `personal_listAccounts`
- `personal_lockAccount`
- `personal_newAccount`
- `personal_unlockAccount`

Example:

```sh
curl \
  -X POST \
  --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_newAccount","params":["password"],"id":1}' \
  --header "Content-Type:application/json" \
  http://localhost:4444
```